# Azure stream-analytics saves data in different format without "$t" "$v"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-stream-analytics

I have an Azure Stream Analytics.

Input is my EventHub.
Output is my CosmosDB with Mongo API

Normally if I save something from Code the Document looks like this:

```
{
"$t" : 3,
"$v" : {
    "_id" : {
        "$t" : 7,
        "$v" : "Z\rSGtþÎ\u0003úL\b"
    },
    "x_right" : {
        "$t" : 1,
        "$v" : 201
    },
    "x_left" : {
        "$t" : 1,
        "$v" : 261
    },
    "time" : {
        "$t" : 2,
        "$v" : "2017-11-16 09:58:42"
    }
},
"id" : "NWEwZDUzNDc3NGZlY2UwM2ZhNGM5OTA4",
"_rid" : "qPdEAK0XVQAEAAAAAAAAAA==",
"_self" : "dbs/qPdEAA==/colls/qPdEAK0XVQA=/docs/qPdEAK0XVQAEAAAAAAAAAA==/",
"_etag" : "\"000047ff-0000-0000-0000-5a0d53470000\"",
"_attachments" : "attachments/",
"_ts" : 1510822727}
```

But my Stream-Analytics will save like this:

```
{
"x_left" : 100,
"x_right" : 200,
...}
```

Different is "$t" and "$v".

Because of this I cant read the saved Documents with mongodb from NodeJS and getting this error:

```
MongoError: Unknown server error occurred when processing this request.
at /Users/m/PycharmProjects/mmobDashboard/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:681:34
at handleCallback (/Users/m/PycharmProjects/mobDashboard/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:171:5)
at setCursorDeadAndNotified (/Users/m/PycharmProjects/mobDashboard/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:505:3)
at nextFunction (/Users/m/PycharmProjects/mobDashboard/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:680:14)
at /Users/m/PycharmProjects/mobDashboard/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:602:7
at queryCallback (/Users/m/PycharmProjects/mobDashboard/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:253:5)
at /Users/marcweisenburger/PycharmProjects/emobDashboard/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'Unknown server error occurred when processing this request.'

**Edit:**
Query from Streamanalytics:

```
Select
*
INTO
    proximitycosmosdb
From
    parkingspaceeventhub
```

proximitycosmosdb is my CosmosDB with Mongo-API
parkingspaceeventhub is my EventHub.

Data will be send to Event hub via MicrosoftFramework for Java in plain Json:

```
{
"x_left": 100,
"x_right": 100,
"y_right": 2,
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show your Stream Analytics query? An example of the Event Hubs input event would be great too.

Comment: i just edited my question with query EventHub input. Thanks!

Comment: i searched a little more, and I think the error is because of the id is not saved as Object. In the AzurePortal i get this error: <{"code":500,"body":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}> @juunas